# Understanding for loops and array indexes

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to know why in this example value[3] is 6 and not 5.

When i = 3, shouldn't value[i] which is 3 be added to 2 (3-1) to give 5?

```
int[] values = new int[5];
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
   values[i] = i + values[i-1];
```

Comment: Try using `System.out.println()` statements to troubleshoot.

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII or a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read about [default values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).
As written there, the `int` type's default value is 0.

So, When you initialize your `int` array in the first line:

```
   int[] values = new int[5];
```

You create an array of size 5, which holds zero values by-default: `values = {0,0,0,0,0}`.

Now, lets move on to the iterations in-hand:

- When `i = 1`: `values[1]` = 1 + `values[0]` (Which is initialized with a default `int` value of 0, as explained) = **1.**
- When `i = 2`: `values[2]` = 2 + `values[1]` = 2 + 1 = **3.**
- When `i = 3`: `values[3]` = 3 + `values[2]` = 3 + 3 = **6.**

Comment: so what does i-1 do?

Comment: @FlyingMonkey in the first iteration? it gets the value of values[0], which is initialized, by-default, to 0.

Comment: in the third iteration, shouldn't i-1 give 2 since 3-1=2?

Comment: @FlyingMonkey  the code line is: "values[i] = i + values[i-1];". In the third iteration the index is 3, so we assign 'values[3]'. The value that we are assigning into it, is the index (3) plus the last cell in the array - in this case, values[3-1]=values[2]=3.

Answer (score 3):

The following assignments are made:

```
values[1] = 1 + 0 (= 1)
values[2] = 2 + 1 (= 3)
values[3] = 3 + 3 (= 6)
...
```

So the `value[3]` is indeed 6.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your array values looks like after the loop runs with the indexs underneath:

```
[0][1][3][6][10]
 0  1  2  3  4
```

So when the loop gets to i=3 like this:

```
values[3] = 3 + values[3-1];
```

its the same as saying

```
values[3] = 3 + 3
```

since the value of values at index 2 is 3

Answer (score -2):

int[] values = new int[5];

<===== At this index 5 value is 6 (0,1,2,3,4,5)

the index's are six because index start from 0;

Comment: spend some time in editing the answer and making it readable.

Comment: You may be answering the wrong thing here.  Or, you may be missing a chunk of the answer here.